# How to remove default contact form validation in Magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, jquery, form-validation, contact-form

I want to remove default contact form validation and add my jquery validation in contact form in Magrnto2.2.5?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 2.2.5 have jquery validation on forms, you need to style it as per your design

Comment: No, it does not has jquery validation, I have added jquery validation, but it is conflicting with the default validation code.If I remove also it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply your custom validation after removing the following:-

File `frontend/templates/form.phtml`

1. Remove `data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'` from `<form>`
2. For each form remove the `data-validate="{required:true}"` inside `<input>` tag.
3. After performing #1 and #2 , apply your custom validation.